# Print do menor número de uma tabela pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Olá,
Tenho um Arquivo CSV com 1000 linhas e 10 colunas, uma das colunas mostra a idade das pessoas, a idade mínima masculina é 0 e a máxima é 96, mas na hora de dar o print o resultado sai com um traço "-".

por exemplo, se printar o min e o max irá sair:

- até 96
  Mas eu preciso que saia:
  0 até 96

segue o código abaixo

```
import pandas as pd

contas = pd.read_csv('contas.csv', sep=';')
Feminino = contas.loc[contas['sexo'] == 'F']
Masculino = contas.loc[contas['sexo'] == 'M']
print('''Faixa etária Feminina: {} até {}'''.format(min(Feminino['idade']),max(Feminino['idade'])))
print('''Faixa etária Masculina: {} até {}'''.format(min(Masculino['idade']),max(Masculino['idade'])))

cont_F = 0
cont_M = 0
for i in contas['sexo']:
    if i == 'F':
        cont_F +=1
    elif i == 'M':
        cont_M += 1
print('Feminino: {} Masculino: {}'.format(cont_F,cont_M))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que apenas no lugar que esteja circulado em vermelho esteja o valor de 0.

Comment: Você tentou `Masculino['idade'].min()`? Pergunto, pois `min(Series)` recupera o NaN como um valor baixo, mas `Series.min()` ignora o NaN

Comment: Já, mas na tabela não está como NaN, está com o valor de 0 mesmo (o numérico)

Comment: Tentou usar o f-string? Algo como `print(f"De {Masculino['idade'].min()} até {Masculino['idade'].max()}")`

Comment: Já, e continua com o traço "-". "Aparece: "De  -    até 96"

Comment: Agora, só com os dados mesmo para tentar saber o que está acontecendo.

Comment: matric;sexo;idade;atend;tuss;servico;plano;vl_unit;vl_ref;qtde
14993;M;0;06/12/2017;20201010;ACOMPANHAMENTO CLINICO DE TRANSPLANTE RENAL NO PERIODO DE INTERNACAO DO RECEPTOR;1077;210.00;202.01;1
10258;M;27;14/03/2016;31602037;ANESTESIA GERAL OU CONDUTIVA PARA REALIZACAO DE BLOQUEIO NEUROLITICO;1145;492.99;316.02;1
BILAT;1046;192.24;160.20;22                         "Tente jogar esses dados criando um arquivo em CSV, ai tem duas idades do sexo masculino, uma com 27 e outra com 0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando os dados postados no comentário.

### Importando biblioteca

```
>>> import pandas as pd
```

### Carregando arquivo

```
>>> contas = pd.read_csv('dados.csv', delimiter=";")
```

### Filtrando dataframe

```
>>> Masculino = contas.loc[contas['sexo'] == 'M']
```

### Verificando filtro

```
>>> Masculino
   matric sexo  idade       atend  ...  plano vl_unit  vl_ref  qtde
0   14993    M      0  06/12/2017  ...   1077  210.00  202.01     1
1   10258    M     27  14/03/2016  ...   1145  492.99  316.02     1

[2 rows x 10 columns]
```

### Imprimindo resultado

```
>>> print('''Faixa etária Masculina: {} até {}'''.format(min(Masculino['idade']),max(Masculino['idade'])))
Faixa etária Masculina: 0 até 27
```

Entretanto, caso vc tenha um hífen nos dados, isso vai gerar o resultado apresentado por você.

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> contas = pd.read_csv('dados-com-hifen.csv', delimiter=";")

>>> contas
   matric sexo idade       atend  ...  plano vl_unit  vl_ref  qtde
0   14993    M     -  06/12/2017  ...   1077  210.00  202.01     1
1   10258    M    27  14/03/2016  ...   1145  492.99  316.02     1

[2 rows x 10 columns]

>>> Masculino = contas.loc[contas['sexo'] == 'M']

>>> Masculino
   matric sexo idade       atend  ...  plano vl_unit  vl_ref  qtde
0   14993    M     -  06/12/2017  ...   1077  210.00  202.01     1
1   10258    M    27  14/03/2016  ...   1145  492.99  316.02     1

[2 rows x 10 columns]

>>> print('''Faixa etária Masculina: {} até {}'''.format(min(Masculino['idade']),max(Masculino['idade'])))

Faixa etária Masculina: - até 27
```

Conforme disse nos comentários, deve ser alguma coisa com seus dados.

Tire a prova dos nove com o comando abaixo

```
>>> contas.loc[contas['idade'] == '-']

   matric sexo idade       atend  ...  plano vl_unit  vl_ref  qtde
0   14993    M     -  06/12/2017  ...   1077   210.0  202.01     1

[1 rows x 10 columns]
```

ou

```
>>> contas.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------   --------------  -----
 0   matric   2 non-null      int64
 1   sexo     2 non-null      object
 2   idade    2 non-null      object    <--- Veja que foi identificado como object e não como int64 como era de se esperar.
 3   atend    2 non-null      object
 4   tuss     2 non-null      int64
 5   servico  2 non-null      object
 6   plano    2 non-null      int64
 7   vl_unit  2 non-null      float64
 8   vl_ref   2 non-null      float64
 9   qtde     2 non-null      int64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(4), object(4)
memory usage: 288.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Desculpa a perdad de tempo, o arquivo tem 999 linhas, e em uma delas tinha de fato um traço, tive que examinar uma por uma até perceber. Agora rodou certinho, muito obrigada !!! :)

Comment: Com o comando `contas.loc[contas['idade'] == '-']` vc teria o índice da linha...